# Integration Inequality for unbounded vs bounded function

Tags: integration, integral-inequality

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \{0,1\}$. $f$ is unbounded. Is the following true?

$$\int_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d} f(x)\ \mathsf dx \geq \int_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d}g(x)\ \mathsf dx.$$

Comment: Without further assumptions nothing can be said. For example, $f$ could take value $+\infty$ on a set of zero measure and $g$ could take value $1$ on a set of finite positive measure, which doesn't satisfy the inequality.

Answer (score 2):

Take $g=1_{[0,1]^d}$, $f= \sum_{n=0}^\infty n \cdot 1_{\{n\}}$, then $f$
is unbounded, but $\int f = 0$ and $\int g = 1$.